# Calculating the Gradient and Hessian of a symbolic function containing Matrices

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have the following function:

[image: Function]

I want to do a couple of things with it:

1. Translate it into a SymPy function (done)

   ```py
   x = MatrixSymbol('x', 2, 1)
   fx = x.T * MatMul(Matrix([[1, 2], [4, 7]]), x) + x.T * Matrix([3, 5]) + 6*Identity(1)
   ```

   - The output using `display()` seems to confirm that it is working:

     [image]
2. Calculate the Gradient and Hessian at point [image: point]:

   - At this point I have tried the following function for the gradient:

     ```py
     v = list(ordered(fx.free_symbols))
     gradient = lambda f, v: Matrix([f]).jacobian(v)
     fxd = gradient(fx, v)
     ```

     However, this outputs `[0, 0]` as the result which is incorrect. The result should be:

     [image: gradient result]
   - For the hessian I tried the following using SymPy's built-in function:

     ```py
     v = list(ordered(fx.free_symbols))
     fxdd = hessian(fx, v)
     ```

     However, this function gives me the following error:

     `ShapeError: Matrix size mismatch: (2, 2) + (2, 1)`

     The output should be:

     [image: hessian result]

So, my question is, how to perform the operations in the second step?

Comment: How was `x` initialized?

Comment: It was initialized as `x = MatrixSymbol('x', 2, 1)`, I will edit my question.

Comment: You can use `fx.diff(x)` for the gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the gradient with `diff`. I'm not sure how to get the Hessian without going through `as_explicit`:

```
In [49]: x = MatrixSymbol('x', 2, 1)
    ...: fx = x.T * MatMul(Matrix([[1, 2], [4, 7]]), x) + x.T * Matrix([3, 5]) + 6*Identity(1)

In [50]: fx.diff(x) # gradient
Out[50]: 
⎡1  2⎤     ⎡1  4⎤     ⎡3⎤
⎢    ⎥⋅x + ⎢    ⎥⋅x + ⎢ ⎥
⎣4  7⎦     ⎣2  7⎦     ⎣5⎦

In [51]: hessian(fx.as_explicit(), x.as_explicit())  # Hessian
Out[51]: 
⎡2  6 ⎤
⎢     ⎥
⎣6  14⎦
```

Comment: Is this still working for you? When I try to run the same code on my end, I get a "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison". I also tried other functions, but still the same.

Comment: It was working with SymPy 1.9. That's a bug that is new since I posted this: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/22476#issuecomment-1546875624